# Row-wise frequency of every word in URL in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, web-scraping, text-analysis

I am very new to programming and need some help in R programming for my University project. I want to create a table with frequency of each word. Input file has around 70000 rows of data such as IDs and webURLs visited by that ID user separated by comma in a csv file:For example:

```
ID                 URLs 
m7fdn              privatkunden:handys, tablets, tarife:vorteile & services:ausland & roaming,privatkunden:hilfe:mehr hilfe:ger,privatkunden:hilfe:service-themen:internet  dsl & ltekonfigurieren
9ufdf              mein website:kontostand & rechnung:meinerechnung:6-monate-Ã¼bersicht zu ihrer rufnummer,mein website:kontostand & rechnung:meinerechnung:kosten
09nd7              404 <https://www.website.de/ussa/login/login.ftel?errorcode=2001&name=%20&goto=https%3a%,mein website:login online user:show form:login.ftel / login),mobile,mobile:meinwebsite:kundendaten (mydata.html),mobile:meinwebsite:startseite (index.html),privatkunden:home,privatkunden:meinwebsite:login.ftel
```

Below code has removed all the special characters from URLs and is giving frequency of word used in whole document. But I don't want it for whole document at once. I want an output per row.

```
text <- readLines("sample.csv")
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
inspect(docs)
toSpace <- content_transformer(function (x , pattern)gsub(pattern, " ", x))  
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "/")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "@")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ",")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ";")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "://")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ":")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "<")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ">")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "-")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "_")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "://")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "&")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ")")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "%")


dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs) 
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
```

Output I am getting is as below:

```
                       word freq  
mein                   mein 1451  
website             website 1038  
privatkunden   privatkunden  898  
meinwebsite     meinwebsite  479  
rechnung           rechnung  474
```

The output I want should be like this:

```
ID               privatkunden  website    hilfe    rechnung  kosten      
m7fdn               4             7         2         7       0
9ufdf               3             1         9         3       5
09nd7               5             7         2         8       9
```

The above table means that the ID m7fdn has 4 times privatkunden in its URLs and 2 times hilfe and so on. The above table is just for sample and does not count the exact words. This table can be as long as many number of words are there. Please help me to get this output. Once I get this table I have to apply Machine Learning.

Comment: It seems you already have what you need:  `as.matrix(dtm)`.  Transpose it if necessary, as your approach has documents as columns. You could use `DocumentTermMatrix` directly instead of transposing: `as.matrix(DocumentTermMatrix(docs))`.

Comment: Hi Jota, I wanted to exclude the IDs  but my method just read whole inout file as single document and added frequency from IDs also. Separating both columns worked. By the way thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 points to mention here:

1) Reading in your data:

```
text <- readLines("sample.csv")
```

gives you a vector with `text[1]` being the **full** first line of your data, `text[2]` being the **full** second line of your data and so on.
What you need for `VectorSource` is one column with only the URLs column. Either use `read.table` or e.g. this:

```
require(tidyr)
text <- readLines("1.txt")
text <- data.frame(a=text[-1]) %>% separate(a, c("ID", "URLs"), sep=6)
```

2) Using your data in `tm`
Make your URLs a corpus by:

```
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text$URLs))
names(docs) <- text$ID
```

Now you do your `tm_map` transformations... At the end you do:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
```

and there you go:

```
> as.matrix(dtm[1:3,1:5])
        Terms
Docs     (index.html (mydata.html 404 ã¼bersicht ausland
  m7fdn            0            0   0          0       1
  9ufdf            0            0   0          1       0
  09nd7            1            1   1          0       0
```